# Creating records with relations between multiple regions and industries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

im having a error with my app, it looks averything fine, but is creating a wrong query, but i have my tables and models right, basically i have a registration of a user that can select more than one regions and industry/area. My error is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hjobs.region_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `region_id` from `region_user` where `user_id` is null)
```

Model User:

```
public function regionsToWork(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Region::class);
    }

    public function industriesToWork(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Industry::class);
    }
```

AuthController:

```
 $user = new User();
 $user->name = $data['name'];
   ...

 $user->regionsToWork()->sync($data['region'], false);
 $user->industriesToWork()->sync($data['industry'], false);
 $user->save();

Tables DB: USER: 

    -id; 
    -email 
    ...

user_industry:

id;
user_id;
industry_id;
user_region:

id;
user_id;
region_id;
```

Migrations user_region_table_creation

```
Schema::create('user_region', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('region_id')->references('id')->on('regions');
        });
```

user_industry_table_creation

```
 Schema::create('user_industry', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->integer('industry_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('industry_id')->references('id')->on('industries');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the pivot table name is different than what it's expecting, region_user as opposed to user_region.

You can manually specify the pivot table name in your belongsToMany method like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Region::class, 'user_region');
```

Comment: sorry, for last answer, now is giving me this error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `user_region` (`region_id`, `user_id`) values (54, ))"

Comment: It means you aren't passing it a user_id which is separate issue, perhaps sync AFTER you save the user so it has an ID to use? On the bright side it means it is now successfully using the right table.

Comment: your right i just updated the ->sync methods after the save(), and works fine, thanks

Comment: For future reference Laravel will expect the name of the pivot table to be segmented in alphabetical order, e.g. R comes before U in the alphabet so it assumed the table would be region_user.